# stop loading action for button in web view is not working

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

when i tap a button in web view which is connected to action-"stop loading" of that web view 
is not working..

its not stops loading even after i press a stop button which is inteded for stop loading content ....

Comment: Can you post some example code? Have you verified (using the debugger) that the method that you expect to be called when the button is tapped is actually being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a UIButton connected to an IBAction, that IBAction should look something like this:

```
- (IBAction)onStopButtonTap:(id)sender {
    [webView stopLoading];
}
```

where webView is an instance variable (presumably an IBOutlet) that references the UIWebView that you want to stop loading.

You can place a breakpoint on the method to verify that it is being called when you expect it to.